# What is this data-folder attribute?

Tags: html, custom-data-attribute

I am seeing an anchor tag with a data-folder attribute. What is this for? I researched it but found no info on it.

Also, I see that it has a data-toggle="dropdown" attribute. I researched that and see that it is a HTML 5 attribute used with the Bootstrap jQuery plugin (dropdown.js). So it's: `data-toggle="dropdown"`.

```html
<a href="" data-folder="4590" class="mega-menu-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Departments<span class=" caret"></span></a>
```

Comment: `data-folder` is an app-specific attribute, used by somebody for their own reasons, most likely in some event handler attached to this element. By the way, is there some particular reason your code sample is indented by 30 spaces?

Comment: You'd probably have to ask the developer or at least search the rest of the site's source for 'data-folder' to find that out. If you want some general info on the data attribute: http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/

Comment: I cant find the closing a tag in the provided code. Do I have change my glass again??? :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data-folder` is custom made [`data-*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) attribute that later is used by some other tool, like CSS or JS/jQuery.

By the name of this attribute `folder` we can tell that it's indicating some reference to folder on server system (maybe ID of departments group?). Not knowing more about what you use we can't tell exactly.

---

If you are using one of supportable libraries (like jQuery), than you can use [Visual Events](https://sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event+2) to check what events does this specific element has.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Custom Data Attribute as specified in [W3C HTML5 specification](http://W3C%20HTML5%20specificationhttps://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes).

Some libraries have methods developed around these type of attributes for easy storing and retrieval of data. Look at the JQuery `.data` method. This method retrieves/stores values via data attributes.

In your case the the following statement will return the value `4590`.

```
$('<a>').data('folder')
```